# Importing CSV's into MySQL(5.6) tables leaves date fields as 0000-00-00

Tags: mysql-5.6, import, csv

During the import from a CSV file created from an MS Access table into a MySQL table it converts all date fields in the csv into  0000-00-00. I use the following Load Data command for the import.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\..\\tableName.txt'
INTO TABLE tableName
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Here's an example line from the CSV file im trying to import.

1,1,5/30/1934 0:00:00,"H","Vancouver, B.C."....

I tried the solution from "[Dates changed to 0000-00-00](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20638/dates-changed-to-0000-00-00)" but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import your .csv file and replace after:

- Make your date column `new_date_column VARCHAR(10)`.
- Import the file.
- `UPDATE` with `REPLACE`.

> `UPDATE db1.table1`
>    `SET  new_date_column = STR_TO_DATE(REPLACE(new_date_column,'/','.'),GET_FORMAT(DATE,'EUR'));`

- Change the datatype of `new_date_column`.

`ALTER TABLE db1.table1 MODIFY new_date_column new_date_column DATE`;

This will convert your `new_date_column` into `XXXX-XX-XX` date format.

Answer (score 2):

Example Database table column names

database_column_1   database_column_2    database_date_column_name

Example CSV data fields

```
fname  lname hireDate
john  smith  09/09/2015

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\/Documents and Settings/Admin/My Documents/datafile.csv' INTO TABLE data_import 
fields terminated by ','
lines terminated by '\r\n'
ignore 1 lines
(database_column_1, database_column_2, @temporary_date_variable)
SET database_date_column = STR_TO_DATE(@temporary_date_variable, '%m/%d/%Y')
```

In the above example you import the local csv data file and assign each data column from the CSV to the matching database column, when you get to the date column you will assign it to a temporary variable (you chose any name for the temporary variable just use the @ symbol at the front of it), then at the end use the SET command to set the database date column equal to the converted CSV value. The STR_TO_DATE function will use the temporary variable as the first parameter and then the format that the **CSV date** is in for the second parameter.